# What does "Preserve timestamps of transferred files" mean in FileZilla?

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, filezilla

I have a web server on a Linux computer, but my development computer is Windows 10 Pro.  There are several GB of files on the web server which I want to be able to update using FileZilla with newer content, without also transferring all of the older content.

I'm not clear on the meaning of *"Preserve timestamps of transferred files"*. Is that the timestamp of the uploaded file or the one already on the web server?  Will it be using the "Creation Date", "Last accessed date" or "Modified date"?

I will be using the FTP transfer option "overwrite file if size differs or source file is newer".

Any comments of suggestions?....RDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that FileZilla will update the *last modification* timestamp of the *destination* file to match that of the *source* file.

The *destination* file is a *remote* file for uploads and a *local* file for downloads.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try and if OK and select this as the answer